# Chart.JS: Stop chart from rescaling when hiding/unhiding a dataset?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have several stacked bar charts which show a bunch of datasets. Often the user needs to hide or un-hide individual datasets. I need several of the features provided by the `responsive` property -- namely, updating chart size when the window is resized, or re-rendering when the underlying data changes.

However, when an individual dataset is hidden or un-hiddden, it's a problem that the chart re-scales so whatever bar has the highest value becomes the top of the scale. It makes it very difficult to understand the effect of hiding/showing a dataset on the various bars' total sizes.

Is there a way to keep all the other "responsive" features, but set it up so hiding datasets doesn't trigger a rescaling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't difficult. There are `min` and `max` properties in your options that overwrite any rearrangements. Just loop over all your data and set the highest value to the `max` property.

```
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: { ... },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 100
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! No idea why I didn't think of that, I've set min/max values for charts plenty of times, just didn't cross my mind to set it each time the data changes. Thanks!